Is there any way where I can automate the process of getting the associated active sites of users in a SharePoint Tenant?
I have a SharePoint tenant with 10,000+++ active sites. I have a list of specific users that I need to pull out all the active sites associated to their account.
We can use the Active Directory UPN of every user as the filter.
Is there any way where I can automate the process of getting the associated active sites of users in a SharePoint Tenant?

Whether you want to get all sites that users have permissions for?
